# black grid around one mesh in object mode

Tags: eevee-render-engine, object-mode

I have some text that I have converted into separate meshes, in object mode one letter has a black cube around it all the others are ok.  I can't understand why I have no modifiers added to the  object and can see no difference when comparing to the other characters?

The cube is visible when in in edit mode?
I haven't come across this before.
[image: Cube around letter]

Comment: can be viewport settings, can be an empty ...or other reasons. If you shouldn't guess - then pls provide blend file and we can check it out. thx.

Comment: Does the object has Viewport Display set to include 'Bounds' > 'Box' ?

Answer (score 2):

I have figured my issue the Viewport Display pointed me in the right direction, some how the Texture space option had been turned on.